# Automata theory - How many Nerode equivalent classes for language $L_k$

Tags: formal-languages, automata

> Given a constant $k$ we will define the language:
>   $$L_k =\{x\#y \mid x \in \{0,1\}^k, y \in \{0,1\}^* \text{ and } x \not=y\}$$
>   How many Nerode equivalent class does $L_k$ have?

I need to show the most tight bounds I can find.

Can anyone give me a clue?

Thanks

[Note for those unfamiliar with the term: Nerode equivalence is defined as $s_1Rs_2$ if and only if $\forall t\in \Sigma^* s_1t\in L \iff s_2t\in L$.]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86536/discussion-on-question-by-chen-doytshman-automata-theory-how-many-nerode-equiv).

Comment: To OP (and spectators), this question has been reworded and [reposted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3021245/12952) to conform more cohesively to our site's editorial standards.